# Just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.03 but system will not boot!

Tags: boot, upgrade

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.03 but system will not boot!
The screen says:

```
udevadm trigger is not permitted while udev is unconfigured.
Gave up waiting for root device. Common Problems:

Boot args (cat/proc/cmdline)
Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
Missing modules (cat/proc/modules; ls/dev)
Alert! /dev/disk/by-uuid/dd1dad95-9bd3-429e-8e94-3f1d49da20e7 does not exist.
Dropping to a shell!

Busybox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```